# Share Truecrypt container

Tags: networking, mount, network-shares, truecrypt

is it possible to put a truecrypt container on a net share and access/mount it form multiple machines (windows) at the same time?

I fear that if both would write the file could be corrupted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sharing-over-network

As written under disadvantages:

> The shared volume may be only
>   file-hosted (not
>   partition/device-hosted). The volume
>   **must be mounted in read-only mode**
>   under each of the systems (see the
>   section Mount Options for information
>   on how to mount a volume in read-only
>   mode). Note that this requirement
>   applies to unencrypted volumes too.
>   One of the reasons is, for example,
>   the fact that data read from a
>   conventional file system under one OS
>   while the file system is being
>   modified by another OS might be
>   inconsistent (which could result in
>   data corruption).

So yes, you can but you do have a high risk in data corruption if you read and write from multiple workstations.

A solution for this would be to open the truecrypt file, share that drive/folder over the network for all other workstations to use. Do note that this is a lot **less secure** then using the truecrypt filesystem locally. (even when using vpn etc.)

Comment: will it mount as readonly automatically if someone has it open already?

Comment: No it will not automatically turn to read-only if the file is currently mounted. You will have to mark it as read-only on every truecrypt instance using the file.

Comment: But you can share a mounted TrueCrypt volume on a network, just like any regular volume. When mounted, a TrueCrypt volume works exactly the same as any other volume; it only becomes corrupted if you dismount it while being used (same as with pen drives and such).