# Multi-user cross-platform client-side on-disk encryption with a SMB/AFS NAS?

Tags: encryption, nas, smb, encfs, afs

I have an old Lacie 5big NAS that does not support encryption. It speaks SMB, AFS and FTP.

I'm looking for a way to store encrypted data on the NAS, at the same time it should be accessible by multiple users.

Some of the users use Linux, some use Windows. Some may use Mac OS X but that's considered less critical for now.

Is there a solution? Can encfs work with a multi-user setup? Truecrypt containers [will only work read-only](https://superuser.com/questions/129121/share-truecrypt-container).

Comment: What do you mean by `client side on-disk encryption`? Doesn't sound making any sense.

Comment: The files are stored encrypted on the disk of the NAS. They are decrypted on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is possible with encfs, "[You can mount the EncFS directory on multiple computers (use the same encfs command) to use your encrypted files on each.](http://www.howtogeek.com/121737/how-to-encrypt-cloud-storage-on-linux-and-windows-with-encfs/)".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a product such as [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) :

> GnuPG allows to encrypt and sign your data and communication, features
>   a versatile key management system as well as access modules for all
>   kinds of public key directories. GnuPG, also known as GPG, is a
>   command line tool with features for easy integration with other
>   applications. A wealth of [frontend applications](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.html) and
>   [libraries](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libraries.html) are available. Version 2 of GnuPG also provides support
>   for S/MIME and Secure Shell (ssh).
>
> GnuPG is Free Software (meaning that it respects your freedom). It can
>   be freely used, modified and distributed under the terms of the GNU
>   General Public License.

[Binary releases](https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html) are available on most Linux distributions and for Windows,
OS X, Debian, Android, OpenVMS, RISC OS,
as well as RPM packages for different OS.

Comment: Using GnuPG would require the user to keep a local copy of the file unless there is some way of doing the encryption with GnuPG transparently and on-the-fly